# Equivariant algebraic K-theory of affine space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, kt.k-theory-and-homology, algebraic-k-theory, equivariant

Unlike algebraic K-theory, equivariant K-theory of affine space (over a field $k$) can be quite nontrivial, depending on the action of the group in question.  For example, if one takes the standard action of $\mathbb G_m$ on $\mathbb A^n$, then the $\mathbb G_m$-equivariant K-theory of $\mathbb A^n$ can be computed using a localization sequence corresponding to the inclusion of the origin inside $\mathbb A^n$.  (In the localization sequence in equivariant K-theory, one uses that the quotient of $\mathbb A^n \backslash \{0\}$ is $\mathbb P^{n-1}$ and uses the projective bundle theorem, for example, to proceed.)

How does one compute $K_i^G(\mathbb A^n)$ in other cases?  Is there a general procedure for doing so?  For example, take $G = \mathbb G_m \times \cdots \times \mathbb G_m$ (product of $n$ copies) and consider the *diagonal action* on $\mathbb A^n$.  How does one compute $K_i^G(\mathbb A^n)$ in this case?  Is it easier to write down the description of $K_0^G(\mathbb A^n)$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In fact, just like in the case of non-equivariant algebraic $K$-theory, there is a homotopy-invariance for equivariant $K$-theory (of nonsingular varieties).  Addressing your question specifically, for any action of an algebraic group $G$ on affine space, the answer is:
$$ K^G_i({\Bbb A}^n) = R(G) \otimes K_i(k), $$
where $k$ is the ground field and $R(G) = K^G_0(k)$ is the representation ring.  If $G$ is a (split) torus, the representation ring is just the group ring of the character group; choosing a basis $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ of characters identifies $R(G)$ with the Laurent polynomial ring ${\Bbb Z}[x_1^\pm,\ldots,x_n^\pm]$.

(The general statement is that when $f\colon X \to Y$ is a $G$-equivariant affine bundle, there is an isomorphism $$f^*\colon G^G_*(Y) \to G^G_*(X),$$ where $G^G_*$ denotes equivariant $K$-theory of coherent sheaves.  For nonsingular varieties $X$ one has $G^G_*(X) = K^G_*(X)$. See Theorem 4.1 of Thomason's foundational paper "Algebraic K-theory of group scheme actions".)

Comment: Is it standard to denote $K$-cohomology with the $*$ as subscript? Please say no.

Comment: @Allen, very regrettably: yes.  Worse, the standard convention of writing K-homology as "G" leads to the atrocity I committed above.  For better or worse, after spending a little time with the literature I am starting to be convinced there are at least some good reasons for all this...

Comment: @DaveAnderson:  Thanks a lot for the answer.  I didn't know about Thomason's this paper.

Comment: @DaveAnderson: I am now having the following doubt:  Consider the standard $\mathbb G_m$ action on $\mathbb A^n$ and consider the localization exact sequence as I had mentioned in the question.  The part of the sequence I am worried about goes as follows:  $ \cdots \to K_1^G(\mathbb A^n) \to K_1(\mathbb P^{n-1}) \to K_0^G(\{0\}) \to K_0^G(\mathbb A^n) \to K_0(\mathbb P^{n-1}) \to 0$.  Now, the groups $K_0^G(\{0\})$ and $K_0^G(\mathbb A^n)$ are the same, however, the map between them in the localization sequence is not an isomorphism.

Comment: So the map $K_1^G(\mathbb A^n) \to K_1(\mathbb P^{n-1})$ is not surjective.  Is this right?

Comment: @Carl, that's partly right: in the localization sequence, the map $K^G_0(0) \to K^G_0({\Bbb A}^n)$ is multiplication by $(1-x)^n$, so it is injective.  Therefore the map $K_1^G({\Bbb A}^n) \to K_1({\Bbb P}^{n-1})$ is surjective.

Comment: @DaveAnderson: Thanks, but why does the map $K_0^G(0) \to K_0^G(\mathbb A^n)$ have that expression?

Comment: @Carl, it comes from taking a Koszul resolution of the structure sheaf of $\{0\}$ considered as an invariant subvariety of ${\Bbb A}^n$.  I think you can find a little more discussion of this kind of thing in Chapter 5 of Chriss-Ginzburg, *Representation Theory and Complex Geometry*.

Comment: @DaveAnderson:  Thanks a lot for the reference, it seems really useful.